How to get products results even its visibility is search in magento graphql
Based on visibility,filter the product in magento 2.
The SKU 111324 having the visibility value is "Search".
Using below graphQL query
Query
query {
  products(
    filter: {
      sku: { eq: "111324" }
    }
  ) {
    items {
      id
      sku
      name
      visibility
    }
  }
}

Response
Got empty results
But If I changed the visibility to Catalog&Search, I got the product response,
Can anyone please explain


To get the product by id or sku you must use products query and
visibility need to be catalog/search.


To search a product you can use search query which is a part of live
search like this, and visbility also need to be catalog/search.

productSearch(
    phrase: String!
    context: [QueryContextInput!]
    current_page: Int = 1
    page_size: Int = 20
    sort: [ProductSearchSortInput!]
    filter: [SearchClauseInput!]
): ProductSearchResponse!


but what you are doing is trying to get to product using products
query while the visibility is search, you can get the product with
search visibility by search query not products query and vise versa.
kindly follow these two documentations:
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/schema/products/queries/products/
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/services/graphql/live-search/product-search/

